# Projection condition evaluating incorrectly

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I must be losing my mind... please look at the following
[image]

And now look at the values that I'm querying on:
[image]
[image]

You can see that ETouchesEvent is null and Event is not... so why does Linq to SQL think ETouchesEvent is not null? It should be 1 for each result in my first picture.

**[Update]**
Below is the generated T-SQL in which you can clearly see that it uses the entityID to check for null

```
{SELECT 
    (CASE 
        WHEN ([t5].[EntityID]) IS NULL THEN @p1
        WHEN ([t5].[EntityID]) IS NULL THEN @p2
        ELSE @p3
     END) AS [value]
FROM (
    SELECT [t4].[ParticipationItemID], [t4].[EntityID]
    FROM (
        SELECT [t0].[ParticipationItemID], [t0].[IsLocalEvent], [t0].[IsProject], [t0].[IsOther], [t0].[EntityID], [t0].[IsEtouchesEvent]
        FROM [ParticipationItem] AS [t0]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Event] AS [t1] ON [t0].[EntityID] = ([t1].[Id])
        WHERE [t0].[IsLocalEvent] = 1
        UNION
        SELECT [t2].[ParticipationItemID], [t2].[IsLocalEvent], [t2].[IsProject], [t2].[IsOther], [t2].[EntityID], [t2].[IsEtouchesEvent]
        FROM [ParticipationItem] AS [t2]
        INNER JOIN [ETouchesEvent] AS [t3] ON [t2].[EntityID] = ([t3].[ETouchesEventID])
        WHERE [t2].[IsEtouchesEvent] = 1
        ) AS [t4]
    ) AS [t5]
WHERE ((([t5].[EntityID]) IS NOT NULL) OR (([t5].[EntityID]) IS NOT NULL)) AND (EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [OrganisationParticipation] AS [t6]
    WHERE (([t6].[OrganisationID]) = @p0) AND ([t6].[ParticipationitemID] = ([t5].[ParticipationItemID]))
    ))
}
```

And this is all the code:

```
    public List<int> GetParticipationYears(int? organisationID)
    {
        var result = (from p in GetParticipation(organisationID, null)
               where p.ETouchesEvent != null || p.Event != null
                select p.ETouchesEvent == null ? 1 : (p.Event == null ? 5 : 0));
               //select p.IsEtouchesEvent ? p.ETouchesEvent.StartDate.Year : (p.IsLocalEvent ? p.Event.StartDate.Year : 0)); //<== this does work!
        return result.Distinct().ToList();
    }

    public IQueryable<ParticipationItem> GetParticipation(int? organisationID, List<int> filterByYears)
    {
        var result = (from pi in DB.ParticipationItems
                      join e in DB.Events on pi.EntityID equals e.Id
                      where pi.IsLocalEvent
                      select pi)
                    .Union(
                      from pi in DB.ParticipationItems
                      join e in DB.ETouchesEvents on pi.EntityID equals e.ETouchesEventID
                      where pi.IsEtouchesEvent
                      select pi);

        if (filterByYears != null)
            result = result.Where(pi => (pi.IsEtouchesEvent && pi.ETouchesEvent != null && filterByYears.Contains(pi.ETouchesEvent.StartDate.Year)) ||
                                        (pi.IsLocalEvent && pi.Event != null && filterByYears.Contains(pi.Event.StartDate.Year)));

        if (organisationID.HasValue)
            return result.Where(pi => pi.OrganisationParticipations.Any(x => x.OrganisationID == organisationID));
        else
            return result;
    }
```

Comment: I suspect it is because both properties are associations using the same ID field. e.g. They both link using an 'EntityID'. And I suspect Linq-to-sql translates this into ISNULL(EntityID) instead of checking whether there is a record available

Comment: This might be a debugger artifact. Try moving `.ToList()` one line above. When you debug, step over the first line (now with `.ToList()`), and only hover the mouse when you reach the second line (which is now just `return result;`).

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic thanks for your suggestions. I just tried it, but it's giving me the same results... I'm thinking now that this is a bug in Linq to SQL.

Comment: Could you please show the sql generated ? We only see a part of it.

Comment: nested inline ifs!!! AAAH!

Comment: @DanielA.White If you find these nested inline ifs confusing then I would love to hear your 'more readable' alternative for what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: you could use the linq functions directly and use standard `if`s.

Comment: @Peter the problem seems to come from the `GetParticipation` method (which generates a strange union, creating confusion for the case when generated). Sorry to ask again, but could you show the whole code of this method ?

Comment: @DanielA.White Care to elaborate on that? I still don't know what you mean. RaphaëlAlthaus: I've added the full code (the commented part works fine btw)

Comment: Why aren't you just checking `IsETouchesEvent` instead of checking for `null`? According to your last comment that works? The code *looks* as though it should work but without having it under a debugger myself it's very difficult to see what the problem is at a glance.

Comment: @DanielA.White Please tell me what the problem with those nested ifs is. I am eager to learn.

Comment: @bodycountPP the problem with nested ifs is purely a readability one, there is no technical issue.

Comment: @James but there isn't any alternative if you wanna do that in linq to sql, or do I miss something ?

Comment: @James I am using `.IsETouchesEvent` now in the if but I would've prefered the `ETouchesEvent == null` option as I'm now risking a nullreferenceexception. But it'll do I guess

Comment: @Peter no, I would say you don't face any NRE (join clauses in your union will avoid these cases).

Comment: I know you're right, it just doesn't feel safe to access a property without checking if the instance exists in the first place, but that's just my way of thinking I guess :-) I'm happy with the IsEtouchesEvent solution as I have commented out in the code example. I still think it has nothing to do with the union though. It's a bug in Linq2SQL where it checks for the ID behind an association instead of verifying if an object exists or not. I could even argue it's expected behavior...

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus you can use functions with in-memory LINQ expressions, just not SQL ones as they can't be translated. However, I think it might be possible to wrap up expressions and invoke them (internally the LINQ providers generate an expression tree anyway). I don't have an issue with nested `if`s, I was just answering @bodycountPP's question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any documentation on this behavior, but it seems that the Linq to SQL translation is looking at the foreign key column behind the relationship (in this case EntityID) to see if its empty instead of the linked record. The generated SQL clearly shows this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.

So the problem comes probably from your Union.

All part of an Union must share same number of fields (with same type).

In your case, the Union works because  `Events` and `ETouchesEvents` must inherit from the same class, or implement the same interface, or just be identical.

But the sql generated by that union can't make the difference between these two types (the CASE WHEN generated doesn't do what you need, which is "coherent").

So you'll have to check on something that sql can discriminate, which seems to be only `IsLocalEvent` and `IsEtouchesEvent`.

So (change the logic if I'm wrong)

```
var result = (from p in GetParticipation(organisationID, null)
               // don't need a where clause, you're doing a join in your union, so any returned part will have an event (which might be a EtouchesEvent or an Event
                select !p.IsEtouchesEvent  
                       ? 1 
                       : !p.IsLocalEvent 
                             ? 5 
                             : 0);
```

I agree that this is not intuitive at all, but sometimes you have to think "SQL", not only "Orm".

It would probably be much clearer if you were working with flattened objects, and not  entities in that case.

A litte bit more.
After your union, any test on `pi.ETouchesEvent` will generate exactly the same sql as `pi.Event` (and they can't be null).

So  I think you can also change the year test to

```
if (filterByYears != null)
            result = result.Where(pi =>  filterByYears.Contains(pi.ETouchesEvent.StartDate.Year);
```